# How do I setup YAML linting in Arcanist?

Tags: yaml, lint, phabricator, arcanist

I can't figure out how to do custom linting pre-diff in Arcanist (YAML, specifically). The [instructions](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist_lint_script_and_regex/) don't explain how to integrate a new linter into my existing `.arclint` configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out on my own, and thought I'd share here in case anyone else has this issue.

The following `.arclint` file does the trick:

```
{
  "linters": {
    "yaml": {
      "type": "script-and-regex",
      "script-and-regex.script": "yamllint",
      "script-and-regex.regex": "/^(?P<line>\\d+):(?P<offset>\\d+) +(?P<severity>warning|error) +(?P<message>.*) +\\((?P<name>.*)\\)$/m",
      "include": "(\\.yml$)",
      "exclude": [ ]
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't extensively tried out that regex, but it works for my purposes so far.

You can [configure Yamllint](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html) by populating a `.yamllint` file in the repository root.